# How to svn annotate / blame a deleted file?

Tags: svn, annotate, blame

**Setup:** File `foo/bar` in my repository got copied (with modifications) to `foo/baz`, and the original was deleted, in r123. This copy was performed manually, not with `svn cp`. Many revisions have passed since.

I now want to see where some of the lines in `foo/baz` came from. After tracking back to `foo/bar`, I try this command:

```
$ svn annotate foo/bar -r 122
svn: warning: W155010: The node '/path/to/checkout/foo/bar' was not found.
svn: E200009: Could not perform blame on all targets because some targets don't exist
```

... but it doesn't work because the file doesn't exist any more!

**Question:** How do I `svn annotate` a file that has been deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richard's answer is ok, but you don't need to know full svn url - `^` character always expands to project url:

```
svn annotate ^/<branch path>/<file path>@rev
```

e.g.

```
svn annotate ^/trunk/README.md@123
```

Comment: Unlike my approach, this requires knowing the path from the root of the repository to the current directory. As with my answer, one way to get that is to use `svn info` and look for the "Relative URL:" line.

Answer (score 2):

After identifying the last revision at which the file existed, you need to use a different form of the `svn annotate` command and look at the history on the SVN server. First, run `svn info` to get the server URL for the current directory:

```
$ svn info
[...]
URL: https://you@wherever.com/svn/project/subproject/trunk
Relative URL: ^/subproject/trunk
[...]
```

The remote revision can be named as `url/path@revision`, as follows:

```
$ svn annotate https://you@wherever.com/svn/project/subproject/trunk/foo/bar@122
```

or

```
$ svn annotate ^/subproject/trunk/foo/bar@122
```

**Edit:** Thanks to Patryk Obara for pointing out that the Relative URL can be used instead.